# React and react-dom still being bundled from the rollup bundler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, rollupjs

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I simply cannot build components with react hooks for rollup.js.
I have tries all the popular comments such as adding skip to my resolve addon and adding externals and adding as peerdependencies in package.json.

My imports is as follows:

```js
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default {
  input: "./src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  external: ["react", "react-dom"],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve({
      skip: ["react", "react-dom"],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
    }),
    postcss({
      plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
    }),
    terser(),
    image(),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `'rollup-plugin-ignore'` worked.

```
  import ignore from 'rollup-plugin-ignore';
  ignore(['fs', 'net', 'react', 'react-dom', 'prop-types', 'PropTypes']),
```

And external like this

```
external: [
  (id) => /^react$|^react-dom$|^@babel\/runtime/.test(id),
];
```